# How to use variable from routes.php in controller

Tags: php, variables, cakephp, controller

In CakePHP have a bunch of unique URL names redirected in `routes.php` file.
Similar to this:

```
$beautiful_urls[0] = '/view/location-name/image-name.html';
Router::connect($beautiful_urls[0], 
                array('controller' => 'Foo','action' => 'bar',3,60));
```

I want to create facebook `like` buttons based on the beautified names. In order to do that I need the `$beautiful_urls` variable I use in the `routes.php` in the `Foo` controller.

How can I reach a variable in routes.php from a controller?
So far I tried to link it with `App::use('routes','Config');` but it's not working. I also thought about sending the values as action parameters, but that doesn't seem like good practice... I know it's not a great idea to mix the config file with a controller's logic but I don't have any better idea so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a good practice or not but my solution was to use the [Configure](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Configure.html) class of CakePHP. It was straightforward to use and accessible everywhere in the code and the config files.

You can save key-value pairs with

```
Configure::write('key','value');
```

and read it again with

```
Configure::read('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not cakephp user but simple search shows that there is class called [ClassRegistry](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ClassRegistry.html).

You can create class BeautifulUrls and store it there. According to docs it's singleton and It can be accessed from everywhere.

Also you can make BeautifulUrls implement ArrayAccess interface so you don't have to change your routes